# Convert .xls to .xlsx for processing in openpyxl trouble

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

I'm trying to avoid a error

```
openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.
```

Following the information from stackoverflow I added a conversion of files using the `pyexcel` library.

```
def put(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
    if 'file' not in request.data:
        raise ParseError("Empty content")
    f = request.data['file']
    filename = f.name
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
        try:
            file = default_storage.save(filename, f)

            # This code added 
            if filename.endswith('.xls'):
                import pyexcel
                _f, _ = filename.split('.')
                pyexcel.save_book_as(file_name=file,
                               dest_file_name=f'{_f}.xlsx')
            ####

            r = get_full_excel_file_response(file, context)
        except InvalidFormatException as e:
            .....
```

But the error is still the same.

I'm looking for the easiest way to convert a file format on a Ubuntu system and Python 3.7. For file processing I'm using only openpyxl. All logic was write for xlsx.

**UPD!!** 
Looks like I found a reason. The file was converted, but the old file (.xml) continued to be sent for processing.
Added this string

```
            file = default_storage.url(f'{_f}.xlsx')
```

Comment: Don't you need the [pyexcel-xlsx](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel-xlsx/) project in order to actually save as `.xlsx`? Yea IIRC that's what you need. Have a look at [pyexcel](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel/) *"Available Plugins"* section and you'll find the support you need.

Comment: @Torxed I'm looking for the easiest way to convert a file format on a Ubuntu system and Python 3.7. For file processing I'm using only openpyxl

Comment: Yes, you can do the approach you're doing if you want. Just use the [pyexcel-xlsx](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel-xlsx/) plugin for `pyexcel` in order to actually write the `.xlsx` format, otherwise you'll just be saving `xls` in a file called `.xlsx`. The file ending have very little to do with anything related to file formats. It's just a human way of reading things. You could just as easily have called it `filename.no_changes_what_so_ever` and it'd still be an `.xls` file so to speak.

Comment: The file was converted, but the old file (.xml) continued to be sent for processing. Updated question.

Comment: Heh, yea you never updated `file`, didn't spot that issue. Spelling error I'd say.

Comment: Yea, thank you for helping!